# Calling static method of

Tags: c++, templates

I've recently encountered code that looks like this

```
template <typename T>
void Foo()
{
    T::Bar();
}
```

I'm confused, how does that compile? There's no constraint on T like in C# generics.

I realize templates are not like generics in that the former are basically glorified macros, so is the case simply that each usage of `Foo` is compiled against the `T` provided in that instance, and given that it has a `Bar()` function it works? Kind of like duck typing?

Is this how it worked since c++03 or is this something new in c++11?

Comment: Yes, templates basically use duck typing. No, they are not glorified macros.

Comment: Right, I guess I went a little overboard with that :) Was this how it worked all along (since c++03) ?

Comment: This is a common technique for what's called Policy Templates, where  `T` specifies some of the implementation.  AFAIK it's been like that as long as templates have been around.  Interestingly, your code expects `Bar` to be e.g. a `static` function in `T`, and you'd need to use `typename T::Bar()` to refer to a type (in which case `Foo` would create a temporary), so the template implementer has a little control over what's substituted.  Static assertions and/or `enable_if` can check other things about the templates - generating errors or skipping instantiation.

Comment: That templates work this way is also why template error messages can be so gnarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how templates work and have worked always, nothing new here in C++11. It compiles if `T::Bar()` is valid for a given type, so it is duck typing as you said. Most of the C++ standard library works based on this principle - e.g. an iterator needs the `operator*` to work, and if you have your own iterators they will work with standard algorithms provided you implement this operator (and other operations required based on the iterator category). You do not need to specify your iterator in any other way - just provide the required operations.

Answer (score 3):

This template function only impose that when substituing the type T, the expression `T::Bar();` is valid, as long as it is valid, it will compile (there is no C#-like constraints in C++) :

Here are two examples using your template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct X
{
    static void Bar() { std::cout << "Bar X\n!"; }
};

struct Y
{
    static std::function<void(void)> Bar;
};

std::function<void(void)> Y::Bar = []() { std::cout << "Bar Y!"; };

template <typename T>
void Foo()
{
    T::Bar();
}


int main()
{
    Foo<X>();
    Foo<Y>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Templates are only compiled when you instantiate them, i.e. by doing

```
Foo<int>();
```

In that case the actual code is generated by substituting `T` for the concrete type that you passed in (which will of course lead to a compile error here since `int` has no static member function `Bar`).

This is by design and has always been around.

Comment: Thanks,I guess my C++ is more rusty than I care to admit (apparently years of C# will do that to you).

Comment: "Templates are only compiled when you instantiate them"...not quite. Particularly importantly, nondependent name lookup are done at template definition time, and compilers are required to issue diagnostics if a nondependent name cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, the formulation is a bit dodgy. What I wanted to emphasise is that for an uninstantiated template no machine code is generated.